# Problem with aptana 3 plugin in eclipse indigo

Tags: eclipse, aptana

I used to code rails using eclipse with radrails plugin, now I have installed aptana 3 plugin in eclipse indigo(last version) and I have several problems:

1) Editor has black background and coloring is different.

2) I don't see the radrails perspective, just web.

How could I solve these issues ?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple:

- Use Preferences > studio > Themes to change the color.
- There is no Rails perspective...only the web perspective now, but it contains all the Rails features already.